# Mongoose schema recursion

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Is it possible to make an recursion in Mongoose?

For example, I want to create nested comments.

Let's consider following example:

```
commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    comment  : String,
    author   : String,
    answers  : [commentSchema] // ReferenceError: commentSchema is not defined
})

productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name      : {type: String, required: true},
    price     : Number,
    comments  : [commentSchema] 
})
```

In SQL it's quite easy to achieve that with keys.

First what come to my mind is to add *parent* field in *commentSchema* which will point to the comment which it is answering, but in that case, if the comments are just a simple objects in array, they do not have ids generated, so this solution cannot be done in current design.

Second solution that come to my mind is to create a separate table for comments, and then they will have their own ids, but is it a good way to do go in mongodb?
I mean it starts looking very similar to the SQL tables design.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [`Schema.add()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-add) method. First you define your schema without the recursive property. After you have assigned the newly created schema to the `commentSchema` variable, you can set it as a property type by calling the `add()` method.

```
const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  comment: String,
  author: String
});

commentSchema.add({ answers: [commentSchema] });
```

Comment: Will the answers have also answers field (sorry, cannot test it now)? I am worried this solution only gives two level comments. Means answers will only have comment and author fields.

Comment: It will work just as you wanted. You can try it in the debugger and inspect the generated schema.